# Modify .NET project files and reference properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am developing an application (C#) which would read project properties/references (and properties of the references) from multiple `csproj` files, and modify their values.

However, the Reference properties like "copy-local" (the properties you see in the properties explorer when you click on a reference) cannot be found in those `csproj` files. Is there a way I can access them and modify their values programatically?

Comment: those files are XML, sooooo...

Comment: i know.I used Microsoft.Build.Evaluation API to parse them and get the properties and references.
However, those XML files (.csproj) do not have properties of references (what i mean is the properties u see in the properties explorer when u click on a reference).
I want to access those properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything is in the XML project file - there's not really anywhere else that this information could be, and it has to be somewhere, right?

Here's an example I've quickly done for you. `Copy Local` is `true` by default for framework assemblies. When you set `Copy Local` to `false`, you get an XML element named `private` included for that reference which itself is set to false.

In this example `System.Core` is set `Copy Local` = `false`.

```
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
```

Comment: That looks like what i want.
I shall try it out...and should anything else arise, I shall add to the thread.
Thanks a ton!!

Comment: If the "private" field is false by default, it does not show in the xml. If i want to access the CopyLocal attribute, check if it is true/false, and set it to false if it is true...how can I do it? In short, how can I check and/or reset the value of the attribute (programatically) without having to override it?

Comment: You'd just check if the `private` node exists and its value is `true`. Try doing it - if you can't then look at XML manipulation, or ask another question.

Comment: The example you give in your answer is wrong (typo I think). For framework assemblies, The default value of `Copy Local` will be `false` and there will be no `<private>` tag in the XML. If however the value is changed, a `<private>` tag will be added to the XML with the same value as `Copy Local`. So if `Copy Local` is `false`, `<private>` will also be `false` (or the tag will be missing). Note: For non-framework assemblies the default value of `Copy Local` is `true`.